# How to call and execute a text file which contains SQL queries in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Suppose I have a text file which has a set of SQL queries. How to call the file and execute it in MYSQL Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to do that in MySQL Workbench. First you have to open a connection to your server from the homescreen. Then you can use either of these methods:

- Use the menu, File -> Run SQL script...
- Open a new sql tab (Ctrl+T or ⌘+T on OSX) and then click on the folder icon in the editor toolbar to open your SQL file (it should have the .sql extension to be selectable). Once loaded you can run it by clicking on the flash icon.

  [image]
- Especially for large SQL files (e.g. dumps) you can use the dump/restore feature, which directly loads a file into your server. For that switch to the admin tab, activate the **Data Import/Restore** section and continue from there. This doesn't have the overhead of loading the script into an editor, do error checking etc. and hence is a lot faster.

[image]